# No test result files were found using search pattern '...\**\TEST-*.xml

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running my test in TFS (Nunit plus Visual Studio with Adapter) and I have set the build definition as below

[image: Publish Test Results]

Build succeeds but no test result file was generated
Does TFS writes this Xml file ?
Log

> 2017-02-08T08:08:40.8151428Z Executing the powershell script: D:\A1\agent\tasks\PublishTestResults\1.0.20\PublishTestResults.ps1
>
> 2017-02-08T08:08:41.0963795Z ##[warning]No test result files were found using search pattern 'D:\A1_work\1\s**\TEST-*.xml'.

Comment: Looks like you are using  [Nunit VS Test Adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTestAdapter)  and [Visual Studio Test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test) task, Which one are you using Nunit2 or Nunit3? Could you share your test framework?

Comment: Can you share the entire build logs?

Answer (score 0):

If the Nunit plus Visual Studio with Adapter means you have two test steps: one for unit tests and the other one for vs tests.

Please also add two "Publish Test Results" step one for Nunit format.

[image]

Also run your test manually on the build server to see if test result file `.trx` generated on the machine.

Comment: .trx file isnot generated

Comment: Should be some environment issue, please make sure your build agent/ server environment are the same as  local. And could you add related build log?